# How to construct an XlaOp?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

There are a number of functions for creating `XlaOp`s from native C++ values. I'm trying to figure out how to use each to construct a graph. I've gone through xla_builder.h and picked out some candidates, omitting overloads and convenience wrappers. The two most likely candidates seem to be

```
// Enqueues a "retrieve parameter value" instruction for a parameter that was
// passed to the computation.
XlaOp Parameter(XlaBuilder* builder, int64 parameter_number, const Shape& shape,
                const string& name);

// Enqueues a constant with the value of the given literal onto the
// computation.
XlaOp ConstantLiteral(XlaBuilder* builder, const LiteralSlice& literal);
```

Am I right in thinking `Parameter` is for "symbols", while `ConstantLiteral` is for constant values? For example, in `f(x) = x + 1`, we'd encode `1` as a `ConstantLiteral`, and then for `x` we could either

1. write `f(x)` as a C++ function, and at application site use another `ConstantLiteral` for our value of `x`, or
2. encode `x` using `Parameter` and build an `XlaComputation` from the corresponding `XlaBuilder`. That said, I'm not clear on how to actually call the `XlaComputation` with a `Literal`, other than with `LocalClient` which doesn't work with to multiple `XlaComputation`s afaict.

What's the difference between these two approaches? Is one better than the other? I notice the former doesn't appear possible for higher-order functions: those which accept `XlaComputation`s.

Next there's

- [`Infeed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/operation_semantics#infeed), which I'd guess is a streaming version of `Parameter`.
- [`Recv`](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/operation_semantics#recv) which looks like a way to pass data between computations, but doesn't actually create a completely new `XlaOp` itself.
- [`ReplicaId`](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/operation_semantics#replicaid), [`Iota`](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/operation_semantics#iota), and `XlaOp CreateToken(XlaBuilder* builder);` appear largely irrelevant for this discussion.

Have I got this right? Are there any other important functions I've missed?